# how to to use lapack library, on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I want to use LAPACK $ BLAS library. Shall I have to define path of lapack. please give me some suggestion.

Comment: **@Jeetu Donderiya** I have an answer with lapack++. It works for me.

Comment: lapack++ provides an easy to use, low level C and C++ interface to the LAPACK FORTRAN library. It provides the complete C interface to all 1350 FORTRAN routines and 421 C++ interfaces to the same routines allowing transparent use of LAPACK workspaces. BLAS (Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines) is a set of efficient routines for most of the basic vector and matrix operations.

Answer (score 2):

For using lapack++ in Ubuntu (I tested it in my Ubuntu 15.04):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential liblapack-dev libblas-dev checkinstall
```

Download **lapackpp-2.5.4.tar.gz** from http://sourceforge.net/projects/lapackpp/files/ to user home.

Unpack it and afterward, in a bash console, move to the folder **lapackpp-X.X.X** and run:

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/liblapackpp.so* /usr/lib/
```

To test lapack++ library save next code as **autov.c++** in your user home:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapackpp/laslv.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

double a[]={ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,
             2.0, 1.0, 4.0,
             3.0, 4.0, 1.0};

    LaVectorDouble v(3);

    LaVectorDouble c(3);

    LaGenMatDouble A(a,3,3);

    LaEigSolve(A,c,v,A);

    cout<<"\neigenvectors are:"<< endl;

    cout << A;

    cout << "\neigenvalues are:"<< endl;

    cout << c;

    return 0;

}
```

Compile and run with:

```
g++ autov.c++ -o autov -llapackpp
./autov
```

The result is:

```
eigenvectors are:
0.505785  0.824038  -0.255232
0.584374  -0.544925  -0.601302
0.634577  -0.154979  0.757161

eigenvalues are:
7.07467
-0.886791
-3.18788
```